# Typescript: Defining a map object with restricted enumerable properties

Tags: typescript

I want to restrict object map values to a certain type, and be able to enumerate its keys.

Having:

```
const obj = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}

type Obj = typeof obj

const obj2: Obj
```

obj2 has typed `a` and `b` props

But I want to restrict obj props to be only strings, I may do

```
const obj: {[name: string]: string} = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}

type Obj = typeof obj

const obj2: Obj
```

obj2 now has NO typed props, just any indexed string property, but I want it to have only `a` and `b` props, but I don't want to do, explicitly enumerate key type (because maybe I have much more then two `a` and `b` props to enumerate):

```
const obj: {[name in ('a' | 'b')]: string} = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}

type Obj = typeof obj

const obj2: Obj
```

Can this be accomplished? Simplier then last snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Basically no. This is not possible. I see that the more reasonable solution can be defining a restrict type as you want and casting to an indexer type when needed:

```
type Indexer = {[name: string]: string};
type Obj = {a: string, b: string};
obj: Obj = {a: 'a', b: 'b'}

// Lodash map
_.map(<Indexer> obj, (val, key) => {})
```

**Note:**

If you you don't want to use Indexers because they break type safety, there is an open discussion on this matter on this [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16316)

If you don't have this concern you can simply define your type like this:

```
type Obj = {a: string, b: string, [name: string]: string}}
```